# dllimport conversion from VC++ to VB function from dll return error due to missing linking lib

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, runtime, dllimport

I'm in the process of converting an SDK for a video camera from C++ to VB.

I've use dll import to import the libraries from the vendor.

it seem to return a valid pointer of class camera when running the first function (the returned pointer is not null):

I declare the function this way:

```
<DllImport("KMpeg4.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
    Shared Function KOpenInterface() As System.IntPtr
```

End Function

then in the code I use it this way:

```
    Dim mcc As structural_MEDIA_CONNECTION_CONFIG2
    Dim last_error As UInteger

    mcc = New structural_MEDIA_CONNECTION_CONFIG2()

    mcc.UserID = "root"
    mcc.Password = "123456"
    mcc.UniCastIP = "192.168.10.242 \0"
    mcc.HTTPPort = 80
    mcc.ContactType = CONTACT_TYPE.CONTACT_TYPE_UNICAST_PREVIEW
    mcc.RegisterPort = 6000
    mcc.ControlPort = 6001
    mcc.StreamingPort = 6002
    mcc.ChannelNumber = 0
    mcc.MultiCastIP = "172.16.1.105\0"
    mcc.MultiCastPort = 5000
    mcc.ConnectTimeOut = 3

    Dim myCamera1 As IntPtr = GlobalMembersSDK10000.KOpenInterface()

    If myCamera1 <> IntPtr.Zero Then


        If GlobalMembersSDK10000.KSetMediaConfig2(myCamera1, mcc) Then
            If GlobalMembersSDK10000.KConnect(myCamera1) Then



                If GlobalMembersSDK10000.KStartStreaming(myCamera1) Then


                    GlobalMembersSDK10000.KPlay(myCamera1)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            last_error = GlobalMembersSDK10000.KGetLastError(myCamera1)
            MessageBox.Show("ACTI camera not configured: error ", last_error.ToString)
        End If
    Else
        last_error = GlobalMembersSDK10000.KGetLastError(myCamera1)
        MessageBox.Show("ACTI camera object not created: error ", last_error.ToString)
    End If
```

When it reach the second function however:

If GlobalMembersSDK10000.KSetMediaConfig2(myCamera1, mcc) Then

this return 0 and thus mean it failed.

I declare it this way:

```
<DllImport("KMpeg4.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Shared Function KSetMediaConfig2(ByVal h As System.IntPtr, ByVal MediaConfig As structural_MEDIA_CONNECTION_CONFIG2) As Boolean

End Function
```

They have a function KGetLastError(myCamera1) that return the error code

the code run, but the function return me an error code that I got from KGetLastError(myCamera1) : code 11

from the camera doc:

error 11 is: SDK10000_ERROR_CAN_NOT_LOAD_AVC_ADAPTOR and the sudgestion is:

Make sure you place your adaptors at
right place with KMpeg4.dll.

I think the AVC adaptors are sub libraries like:

AADP.dll , AFADP.dll ,FFMCODEC.dll

So my question is, how can I figure out which library (or AVC as they call them) is not linking to  KMpeg4.dll and more importently, how do I make sure those sub libs links?

Do I miss use DllImport?

From the advice below, I've used the Sys Internals Process monitor to isolate a problem with the KMpeg4.dll but all the call seam successfull:

```
12:23:07.7439127 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    CreateFile  \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
12:23:07.7445053 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    QueryBasicInformationFile   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS CreationTime: 28/09/2013 12:06:02 AM, LastAccessTime: 28/09/2013 12:06:02 AM, LastWriteTime: 27/09/2013 4:48:14 PM, ChangeTime: 28/09/2013 12:06:02 AM, FileAttributes: N
12:23:07.7445836 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    CloseFile   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS 
12:23:07.7452012 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    CreateFile  \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Execute/Traverse, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
12:23:07.7698233 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    CreateFileMapping   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: 
12:23:07.7698524 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    QueryStandardInformationFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS AllocationSize: 475,136, EndOfFile: 474,624, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
12:23:07.7699283 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 4,096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.7700397 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 438,784, Length: 16,384, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.7702314 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    CreateFileMapping   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS SyncType: SyncTypeOther
12:23:07.7702835 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    Load Image  \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Image Base: 0x52940000, Image Size: 0x7a000
12:23:07.7703029 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 377,344, Length: 16,384, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.7704030 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    CloseFile   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS 
12:23:07.7704268 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 423,936, Length: 14,848, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.7711082 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    CreateFile  \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
12:23:07.7712269 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    QueryDeviceInformationVolume    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
12:23:07.7723003 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    CloseFile   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS 
12:23:07.7723960 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 397,824, Length: 15,872, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.7724840 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 348,672, Length: 16,384, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9494865 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 413,696, Length: 10,240, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9790363 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 254,976, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9791607 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 308,224, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9792672 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 365,056, Length: 12,288, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9794291 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 287,744, Length: 20,480, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9797190 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 222,208, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9799430 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 189,440, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9803362 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 340,992, Length: 7,680, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9805623 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 95,232, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9809615 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 62,464, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9813405 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 156,672, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9822537 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    CreateFile  \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
12:23:07.9823453 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    QueryDeviceInformationVolume    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
12:23:07.9832491 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    CloseFile   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS 
12:23:07.9847202 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 9,216, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9848623 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 1,024, Length: 8,192, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9849781 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 128,000, Length: 28,672, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:23:07.9859849 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 41,984, Length: 20,480, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:03.8466978 AM WifiATR.exe 4004    QueryNameInformationFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Name: \vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll
12:27:32.1381127 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    CreateFile  \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
12:27:32.1387424 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    QueryBasicInformationFile   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS CreationTime: 28/09/2013 12:23:15 AM, LastAccessTime: 28/09/2013 12:23:15 AM, LastWriteTime: 27/09/2013 4:48:14 PM, ChangeTime: 28/09/2013 12:23:15 AM, FileAttributes: N
12:27:32.1388094 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    CloseFile   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS 
12:27:32.1399486 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    CreateFile  \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Execute/Traverse, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
12:27:32.1644811 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    CreateFileMapping   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: 
12:27:32.1645109 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    QueryStandardInformationFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS AllocationSize: 475,136, EndOfFile: 474,624, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
12:27:32.1646074 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 4,096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.1647253 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 438,784, Length: 16,384, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.1649146 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    CreateFileMapping   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS SyncType: SyncTypeOther
12:27:32.1649687 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    Load Image  \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Image Base: 0x528d0000, Image Size: 0x7a000
12:27:32.1649885 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 377,344, Length: 16,384, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.1650963 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    CloseFile   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS 
12:27:32.1651205 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 423,936, Length: 14,848, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.1657563 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    CreateFile  \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
12:27:32.1658609 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    QueryDeviceInformationVolume    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
12:27:32.1669645 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    CloseFile   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS 
12:27:32.1670638 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 397,824, Length: 15,872, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.1671421 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 348,672, Length: 16,384, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3486441 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 413,696, Length: 10,240, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3655188 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 254,976, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3657121 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 308,224, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3658058 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 365,056, Length: 12,288, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3658999 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 287,744, Length: 20,480, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3660399 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 222,208, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3661344 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 189,440, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3663286 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 340,992, Length: 7,680, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3664307 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 95,232, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3665679 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 62,464, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3666741 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 156,672, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3673361 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    CreateFile  \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
12:27:32.3674520 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    QueryDeviceInformationVolume    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
12:27:32.3682142 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    CloseFile   \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS 
12:27:32.3683756 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 9,216, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3707666 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 1,024, Length: 8,192, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3708817 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 128,000, Length: 28,672, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
12:27:32.3734798 AM WifiATR.exe 2448    ReadFile    \\vboxsrv\ROOT\home\william\Development_new\pipe robot\code\New_GUI_software\src\bin\x86\Debug\KMpeg4.dll   SUCCESS Offset: 41,984, Length: 20,480, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
```

I the previous print out I forgot to remove the KMpeg4.dll filter but even when I look without the filter, the function that the program is looking for is fund in one path or another.

Thanks

William

Comment: The advice is exactly the same as for your previous question, make sure that *all* the DLLs that this component needs are copied.

Comment: So you are saying, there is nothing wrong with the code? I've done the steps you advised on the last question on all the dll the SDK did provide to me but I still have the same problem excepted that because it is within the library, I don't know how to track which extra lib KMpeg4.dll is looking for. I was worry I should marshal an argument or use something different than DllImport, like Declare Auto or delegate

Comment: Of course I don't know either, this is not exactly a common component.  If it is not in the manual or readme file then contact the owner of the component for deployment advice, they always have it if it isn't straight-forward.  You could also run SysInternals' ProcMon, you'll see your program searching for a DLL and not finding it.  It could also be a configuration file setting that's wrong or missing, anything is possible here.

Comment: all the provider dll are in the main directory with copy if newer. I did contacted the provider about this mater but I'm waiting, will try SysInternals' ProcMon

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the issue. It was code related.

I needed to Marshal the Structure converted from C++ that I was passing as argument:

original typedef structure:

```
typedef struct structural_MEDIA_VIDEO_CONFIG2
{
    short dwEncoder;            // 1:MPEG4 4:MPEG4 5:H264
    short dwTvStander;          // 0:NTSC 1:PAL
    short dwVideoResolution;    // See the definition above
    short dwBitsRate;           // See the definition above
    short dwQuality;            // 0 ~ 100 : Low ~ High
    short dwVideoBrightness;    // 0 ~ 100 : Low ~ High
    short dwVideoContrast;      // 0 ~ 100 : Low ~ High
    short dwVideoSaturation;    // 0 ~ 100 : Low ~ High
    short dwVideoHue;           // 0 ~ 100 : Low ~ High
    short dwFps;                // 0 ~ 30 frame pre second
} MEDIA_VIDEO_CONFIG2;
```

converted structure in VB:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Public Structure structural_MEDIA_CONNECTION_CONFIG2
    Public ContactType As Integer

    Public ChannelNumber As Byte ' For URL Command CHANNEL tag, when set it to 0, URL command won't bring CHANNEL tag, or the URL command will bring CHANNEL=ChannelNumber tag  )
    Public TCPVideoStreamID As Byte ' 0 based to specify video track, value 0 to 255 for 1 to 256 video track
    Public RTPVideoTrackNumber As Byte ' set it to 0, ARTP will use 1st video track,  1 to 255 is for specify video track
    Public RTPAudioTrackNumber As Byte ' set it to 0, ARTP will use 1st audio track,  1 to 255 is for specify audio track

    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=32)> _
    Public UniCastIP As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=32)> _
    Public MultiCastIP As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=32)> _
    Public PlayFileName As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=32)> _
    Public UserID As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=32)> _
    Public Password As String
    Public RegisterPort As UInteger
    Public StreamingPort As UInteger
    Public ControlPort As UInteger
    Public MultiCastPort As UInteger
    Public SearchPortC2S As UInteger
    Public SearchPortS2C As UInteger
    Public HTTPPort As UInteger
    Public RTSPPort As UInteger
    Public Reserved1 As UInteger
    Public Reserved2 As UInteger

    Public ConnectTimeOut As UShort
    Public EncryptionType As UShort
End Structure
```

And I needed to change to ByRef instead of ByVal for the declared argument of the function:

```
<DllImport("KMpeg4.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Shared Function KSetMediaConfig2(ByVal h As System.IntPtr, ByRef MediaConfig As structural_MEDIA_CONNECTION_CONFIG2) As Boolean
End Function
```

This got me to the next stage

William